# Moment.JS deprecation warning

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I am updating an old system which uses moment.js for dates.

Currently, it uses this code as a means of formatting;

```js
var localTime  = moment.utc(this.created_at).toDate();
localTime = moment(localTime).calendar();
```

I have tried to convert the date to using `toISOString` before passing it to the final `localTime`. However, I keep getting the same warning.

---

Warning

```
Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date.
```

---

Below is the date format generated by Twitter in an XML file.

```xml
<created_at>Mon Oct 16 10:31:26 +0000 2017</created_at>
```

---

Here I attempt to convert it to an ISO.

```js
var isoString  = moment.utc(this.created_at).toISOString();
localTime = moment(isoString, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sss');
```

---

The time it logs

```
2017-10-16T10:31:26.000Z
```

---

When I update the minified moment.js locales library I get a similar warning.

```
moment-with-locales.min.js:1 Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
```

Why is the date falling back to `Date()` even though when I log it to the console I get the ISO format. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your input is not in ISO 8601 recognized format, neither in RFC 2822 format, you have to use [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

Here a working sample:

```js
var created_at = 'Mon Oct 16 10:31:26 +0000 2017';
var localTime  = moment.utc(created_at, 'ddd MMM DD HH:mm:ss ZZ YYYY');
localTime = localTime.calendar();
console.log(localTime);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Perfect! So simple, was convoluting it for myself. Will definitely remember next time! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try `var localTime  = moment.utc(new Date(this.created_at)).toDate();` where this.created_at is `Mon Oct 16 10:31:26 +0000 2017`

Comment: That is doing exactly what moment.js is trying to say "don't do this".

Comment: agreed. moment.js discourages the use of javascript's date function. This is just a hack around the parsing of the text